# Match against substrings in array

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I have an array:

```
my_arr = ["PR", "PM", "EM", "SM", "ST"]
```

and a string:

```
my_str = "5012PR152"
```

I would like to see if the string includes any of the strings in the array. If the strings in the array was just one, this would work:

```
my_str.include?("PR")
```

but I can't pass the array of strings as an argument to `include?`. How can I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We need to see your attempt at solving the problem. This doesn't show much effort, which is important. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_arr.inject(false) { |m, e| m ||= my_str.include? e }
```

This returns the right answer but lacks an early-out; I don't see a pithy way to get that.

Alternatively, it might be fun to monkey-patch String for this...

```
class String
  def anyinclude? a
    a.each do |e|
      if include? e
        return true
      end
    end
    return false
  end
end

my_arr = ["PR", "PM", "EM", "SM", "ST"]
p "5012PR152".anyinclude? my_arr
```

Comment: Awesome part of this would be that I could return 'e' rather than true if there is a match.

Comment: Great idea, and in that case, return nil instead of false.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Enumerable method `any?` which takes a block and will return true if any of the results are anything but false/nil.

Then you can use your `my_arr` array in the block to check against the string with the `indlude?()` method.

That will end up looking something like this:

`my_arr.any? { |a| my_string.include?(a) }`

Alternatively, you can create a method that will do this for you for future use. That could look something like this:

```
class String
  def any_include?(array)
    array.any? { |a| include?(a) }
  end
end
```

Which you could call on a string with `my_str.any_include?(my_arr)`

```
2.1.2 :001 > class String
2.1.2 :002?>     def any_include?(array)
2.1.2 :003?>         array.any? { |a| include?(a) }
2.1.2 :004?>       end
2.1.2 :005?>   end
 => :any_include? 
2.1.2 :006 > my_arr = ["PR", "PM", "EM", "SM", "ST"]
 => ["PR", "PM", "EM", "SM", "ST"] 
2.1.2 :007 > my_str = "5012PR152"
 => "5012PR152" 
2.1.2 :008 > my_str.any_include?(my_arr)
 => true
```

Comment: Please don't toss out code. Explain why the code is useful and why your answer works best. Don't hand someone a fish, teach them how to fish.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def include_substring(str, arr)
  str.chars.each_cons(2).to_a.any? { |a,b| arr.include?([a,b].join('')) }
end

include_substring('5012PR152', ['PR', QZ'])
=> true
```

Breakdown

`chars` - Breaks a string into an array of every character

`each-cons(2)` - Partitions this array into chunks of two

`any?` Find if any elements in the array match the following condition

In the following block, we want to pass in both elements as parameters and see if the array of combos includes the concatenation of the said two elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_arr = ["PR", "PM", "EM", "SM", "ST"]

r = Regexp.union(my_arr)
  # => /PR|PM|EM|SM|ST/

["5012PR152", "5512ST011", "5012ME031"].map { |s| !!(s =~ r) }
  #=> [true, true, false]
```

`!` converts a truthy value (anything other `nil` and `false`) to `false` and a falsy value (`nil` or `false`) to `true`. Therefore, `!!` converts a truthy value  to `true` and a falsy value to `false`.  You could alternatively write the block as

```
{ |s| s =~ r ? true : false }
```